# Cannot register custom protocol in tauri

Tags: reactjs, rust, tauri, content-security-policy

I am trying to register a custom url scheme in a tauri application. But in the app I am getting an error `"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"` as shown in the image below.

I am calling it as an image source like:

```html
<img src="photo://localhost?id=1" />
```

[image: Screenshot of error page]

in `main.rs` I have registered it using:

```rs
fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .register_uri_scheme_protocol("photo", move |app, request| {
            dbg!(&request);

            ResponseBuilder::new()
                .status(200)
                .body(Vec::new())
        })
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

In my `tauri.conf.json` I have set the `csp` to:

```json
"security": {
    "csp": "default-src 'self'; img-src photo://*;"
},
```

In my `Cargo.toml` I have made the `custom-protocol` feature as default using this:

```ini
[features]
default = ["custom-protocol"]
custom-protocol = ["tauri/custom-protocol"]
```

I have tried to run:

```bash
cargo tauri dev -f custom-protocol # Even tried without fetaures flag
```

But every time I am getting this error.

Am I missing something?

Note: Added output from `cargo tauri info`

```
[✔] Environment
    - OS: Windows 10.0.22631 X64
    ✔ WebView2: 120.0.2210.91
    ✔ MSVC: Visual Studio Community 2022
    ✔ rustc: 1.77.0-nightly (e51e98dde 2023-12-31)
    ✔ cargo: 1.77.0-nightly (ac6bbb332 2023-12-26)
    ✔ rustup: 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)
    ✔ Rust toolchain: nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (environment override by RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN)
    - node: 21.5.0
    - yarn: 3.6.1
    - npm: 10.2.5

[-] Packages
    - tauri [RUST]: 1.5.4
    - tauri-build [RUST]: 1.5.1
    - wry [RUST]: 0.24.7
    - tao [RUST]: 0.16.5
    - tauri-cli [RUST]: 1.5.9
    - @tauri-apps/api [NPM]: 1.5.3
    - @tauri-apps/cli [NPM]: 1.5.9

[-] App
    - build-type: bundle
    - CSP: default-src 'self'; img-src photo://*;
    - distDir: ../dist
    - devPath: http://localhost:3333/
    - framework: React
    - bundler: Vite
```

Comment: This feature is highly dependent on the underlying system. Have you read this[1]? What OS are you testing this on?

    [1] https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/323

Comment: The issue seems to be about deep-linking, but it is not my concern. I want to request resources from the backend using this as it seems to be faster that default JSON IPC

Comment: I tried your code, and apart from CORS issues that I didn't bypass, the code seems to work. I get logs like these: `[src/main.rs:34] &request = Request {
    method: GET,
    uri: "photo://localhost:8080/tauri",
    headers: {},
    body: [],
}` Can you share exactly how you make the requests? I used the `fetch` api.

Comment: Added call source in question. I will also try and use it as an image source. Thanks a lot

Comment: As far as I know, custom URI protocols can only used to launch external applications - not to define a new protocol for loading a resource. Am I completely wrong about this?

Comment: Try using this function https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/tauri/#convertfilesrc - The scheme will be `https://<scheme>.localhost/` on windows (you also need to adapt your csp accordingly). The linked function will add the correct scheme and escape the url.

Comment: Also seen this. It only works when the image is on disk, but in my case I provide it with the binary values directly

Comment: I tried with your image source and it seems to work fine on Ubuntu, no errors and the log is as expected. Do you have an Ubuntu machine you can try, at least to see if it's a Windows specific thing? @Codebling But that's what's happening here, the Tauri app is defined as the app to handle that URI scheme, launching, in itself, is a side effect, which is not necessary here.

Comment: Ok let me try in an Ubuntu machine

Comment: @TachyonicBytes is that because Tauri is using a customized browser? I wouldn't expect that to work in a normal browser - after launching app there's no expectation of a response. But maybe I am wrong about the whole thing. Either way, seems like it does indeed work, at least in Tauri

Comment: @Codebling a normal browser also has a few different uri schemes like `data:`, `blob:`, `filesystem:`, etc.

Comment: @TachyonicBytes can you share your frontend code?

Comment: I have an app where I try all these. It's here [1]. I haven't commited your code for now, but it should be straightforward.

    [1] https://github.com/tachyonicbytes/so-answers/tree/master/77524788/tauri-app/src

Comment: I pushed the changes

Comment: @TachyonicBytes still getting same error unfortunately. Anyways thanks for spending time to help me.